# Tkinter global name keeptime not defined

Tags: python, tkinter, label, global, nameerror

```
import Tkinter
import random
from time import sleep

class simpleapp_tk(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()


        self.labelVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
        label = Tkinter.Label(self,textvariable=self.labelVariable,anchor="w",fg="blue",bg="gold")
        label.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='EW')
        self.labelVariable.set(u"Press button to begin!")


        self.button = Tkinter.Button(self,text=u"Start",
                                command=self.usertypetest(0),fg="black",bg="green")
        self.button.grid(column=2,row=0)


        self.labelVariable2 = Tkinter.StringVar()
        label2 = Tkinter.Label(self,textvariable=self.labelVariable2,anchor="w",fg="blue",bg="gold")
        label2.grid(column=1,row=0,sticky='EW')
        self.labelVariable2.set(u'Time')


        self.entryVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self,textvariable=self.entryVariable,fg="black",bg="white")
        self.entry.grid(column=0,row=1,columnspan=2,sticky='EW')
        self.entryVariable.set(u"")


        self.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.resizable(True,True)


    def keeptime(num1):
        self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)
        timer = num1
        t = 0
        while timer < 1:
            self.labelVariable2.set(t)
            sleep(.01)
            t += .01



    def usertype(self):
        randletter = random.choice('qwer')
        self.labelVariable.set("Press "+randletter)
        userinput = self.entryVariable.get
        while userinput == '':
            pass
        if userinput == randletter:
            return 'Correct'    
        else:
            return 'Incorrect'

    def usertypetest(self,num1):
        keeptime(num1)
        for x in range(20):
            result = usertype()
            print result
            if result == 'Correct':
                y = y+5
            else:
                y = y-2
        timer += 1
        self.labelVariable.set(str(y)+' is your score')






if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = simpleapp_tk(None)
    app.title('LoL Practice')
    app.geometry("700x50")
    app.configure(background='black')
    app.mainloop()
```

That is my program. The goal of this program is that when the user clicks start, a timer will start, printing to a label, and they will be shown letters randomly chosen from (Q,W,E,R), which they must type as fast as possible. The program will time them and give them a score based on their errors at the end, and also stop the timer. The problem I am having is that it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Brett/Documents/shellrunpractice", line 83, in <module>
    app = simpleapp_tk(None)
  File "C:/Users/Brett/Documents/shellrunpractice", line 9, in __init__
    self.initialize()
  File "C:/Users/Brett/Documents/shellrunpractice", line 22, in initialize
    command=self.usertypetest(0),fg="black",bg="green")
  File "C:/Users/Brett/Documents/shellrunpractice", line 66, in usertypetest
    keeptime(num1)
NameError: global name 'keeptime' is not defined
```

This has been Fixed!

Also, before I made some changes, the code did not produce errors, but when I clicked the button the program just hung. I am wondering if you guys could find any other errors in my code that could be causing that, and if so how to do it. I realize my code is very bad, I'm just starting in Tkinter, and I'm not entirely sure how everything works yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should actually use `self.keeptime(num1)` instead of `keeptime(num1)` to access class methods and you should use `self` as the first argument of the `keeptime` method

```
def keeptime(self,num1):
    self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)
    timer = num1
    t = 0
    while timer < 1:
        self.labelVariable2.set(t)
        sleep(.01)
        t += .01
```